# How to build some java files to one jar using gradle java-plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, source-sets

I want to compile some java files to one jar file with gradle.
The goal is to add them to a jar and check the dependcies of the tests.
Maven should integrate the junit libary.
I also want to apply some kind of filter to test only the files with `*Tests.java`
The `build.gradle` file is in the same directory as the `src` folder.

My file structure(folders or filenames cannot be changed):

```
src/eu/conflicts/Conflicts.java
src/eu/conflicts/ConflictsTests.java
src/eu/utils/BuggyUtils.java
src/eu/utils/BuggyUtilsTests.java
```

After running `gradle -b build.gradle jar` I got the error message: `Could not find the main method`

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

sourceSets {
   main {
      conflicts {
         srcDir = 'src/eu/conflicts'
      }
      utils {
         srcDir = 'src/eu/utils'
      }
   }

   test {
      conflicts {
         srcDir = 'src/eu/conflicts'
      }

      utils {
         srcDir = 'src/eu/utils'
      }
   }
}

jar {
   baseName = 'xy'
   version = '0.1'
   manifest {
      attributes("Implementation-Title": "xy",
                 "Implementation-Version": 0.1)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source sets definition is incorrect. Java plugin only supports `java` and `resources` source types within a source set. Each source set can have an arbitrary name. If you name your source set `main` it will customise the one used by convention by the jar task.  So:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src'
      exclude '**/*Tests.java'
    }
  }

  test {
    java {
      srcDir 'src'
      include '**/*Tests.java'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your source sets seem to be incorrect, and you don't really need to amend jar task if you are not bothered about the artifact being build.

- To run all tests and compile your files you just need to run `build` task, it depends on `assemble` and `check` which depends on other tasks like `test`, `compile` etc. To use it you need to `apply plugin: 'java'`.
- Gradle will build a single artifact (if you use build task) compiling all you want, by default packing your main sources into a jar without test sources.
- Gradle is going to run all tests in test sources (Using test task bundled in build task) discovered via annotations.
- You can amend all that using SourceSets{} in your script to point to non-default structures

Try maybe this:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java{ 
        srcDirs = ['src/eu/conflicts', 'src/eu/utils'] 
        include '**/*.java'
    }

    test.java{
        srcDirs = ['src/eu/conflicts', 'src/eu/utils'] 
        include  '**/*Tests.java'
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to compile all java files and test them and then build them to one jar file.

Comment: and if you run gradle build? this is what it should do.

Comment: i got the same error message when i tried it with build

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project '2017ProjectTeam5_1'.
> Could not find method main() for arguments [_01356151_bkxl5o60k8o88kpv3g258s1b1$_run_closure3$_closure5@53cf9c99] on root project 'xy'.

Comment: then which package are tests and which production ?

Comment: in every package is one production class and one test class.
It's not possible to change that. All classes with *Test.java should be testclasses and the other should be added to the jar

Comment: I'm not sure but try something like this, and delete jar{} closure your don't really need it unless you really care about version manifest and name.

Comment: Gradle test discovery should be driven with annotations, then hopefully if you have tests Gradle should run them, but you need to tell it where are those if it's not a default sources tree